# Android app crashes when back button is pressed

Tags: java, android, crash

I have run into an annoying crash in my app when the user clicks the back button.

In my app, i have 3 relevant activities:

- MainActivity: shows a list of Persons
- PersonActivity: shows a list of all the Payments of a Person
- AddPaymentActivity: has input elements to add a Payment to a Person

From MainActivity the user can either tap on a Person's name in the list to go to PersonActivity or use a "+" button next to the Person's name and jump directly into AddPaymentActivity. In PersonActivity there is a "+" button that leads to AddPaymentActivity, too.

The Perons data is stored in a Java Person class that implements the Serializable interface. When starting an Activty i forward the Person Object via

```
intent.putExtra(MainActivity.PERSON_MESSAGE, person);
```

When i go from MainActivity directly into AddPaymentActivity (via "+"), the back button works fine. If i however use start AddPaymentActivity from PersonActivity, my application crashes with a null pointer exception.

Using the debugger i noticed that PersonActivity.onCreate() is called (again?) when the back button is pressed. Why does this happen when going back form AddPaymentActivity to PersonActivity? And why does that NOT happen when going back from AddPaymentActivity to MainActivity? What can i do to fix the problem?

Stack trace:

```
01-13 10:11:01.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1022): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-13 10:11:01.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1022): Process: de.emteg.cashsplit, PID: 1022
01-13 10:11:01.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1022): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.emteg.cashsplit/de.emteg.cashsplit.PersonActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-13 10:11:01.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
01-13 10:11:01.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
01-13 10:11:01.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-13 10:11:01.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
01-13 10:11:01.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-13 10:11:01.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-13 10:11:01.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
01-13 10:11:01.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 10:11:01.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-13 10:11:01.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-13 10:11:01.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
01-13 10:11:01.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-13 10:11:01.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1022): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-13 10:11:01.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:425)
01-13 10:11:01.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at de.emteg.cashsplit.PersonActivity.onCreate(PersonActivity.java:37)
01-13 10:11:01.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
01-13 10:11:01.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-13 10:11:01.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
01-13 10:11:01.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     ... 11 more
```

MainActivity.onCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_overview);

    persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

            // Populate list with some test person objects
    Person p = new Person("Frank");
    p.getPayments().add(new Payment("test1", new BigDecimal(5.7)));
    persons.add(p);

    p = new Person("Peter");
    persons.add(p);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    PersonAdapter adapter = new PersonAdapter();
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    // output....
}
```

PersonActivity.onCreate():

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_person);

    Intent intent = getIntent();        
    this.person = (Person) intent.getSerializableExtra(MainActivity.PERSON_MESSAGE);
    this.share = new BigDecimal(intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.SHARE_MESSAGE));
    this.totalSum = new BigDecimal(intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.SUM_MESSAGE));
    this.diff = person.getSum().subtract(share);

    setupActionBar();

    // output...
}
```

AddPaymentActivty.onCreate():

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_payment);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    this.person = (Person) intent.getSerializableExtra(MainActivity.PERSON_MESSAGE);

    if (intent.hasExtra(MainActivity.PAYMENT_MESSAGE)) {
        this.payment = (Payment) intent.getSerializableExtra(MainActivity.PAYMENT_MESSAGE);
        // output....
    } else {
        this.payment = null;
        // output...
    }

}
```

Comment: Hmm yeah, If you could post the stacktrace, that would be great.

Comment: seems your activity is popped out of stack when you call it, post your on create method of the class you getting crash in. By your log it seems something being passed is actually never passed

Comment: The crash in PersonActivity.onCreate() happens when this line of code is executed:

`Intent intent = getIntent();`     
`this.person = (Person) intent.getSerializableExtra(MainActivity.PERSON_MESSAGE);`

But i would think, that pressing the back button does not fully creates the activity again. It does not create MainActivity. The crash is logical, because the back button does not put the extras. But why does onCreate happen at all?

Comment: you better put code for your three onCreates() otherwise it would just be a guess to try whats wrong there!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in one of those 2 lines :

```
this.share = new BigDecimal(intent.getStringExtra(OverviewActivity.SHARE_MESSAGE));
this.totalSum = new BigDecimal(intent.getStringExtra(OverviewActivity.SUM_MESSAGE));
```

It seems that one of your 2 `getStringExtra` return null.

Answer (score 0):

It must be because of a null pointer exception which causes your app to crash.

First, check if in your PersonActivity needs a value that is not passed/set when back button is pressed from your AddPaymentActivity.

You may also override the onResume() function, it will be called when back button is pressed.

Comment: I pass the necessary object through intent.putExtra(). How can i do this when the back button is pressed?

Comment: you may override onBackPressed function on your AddPaymentActivity:


`@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     super.onBackPressed();  // optional
     //you may put your intent here, putExtra, startActivity 
}`

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have not added  finish(); after your intent.The intent/activity you wish to return to from the previous activity,when adding this intent to the parent activity,make sure that the parent activity invoking this intent does not have  finish();.for example:

Main Activity calling payment activity:

```
Intent d = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                PaymentActivity.class);
        startActivity(d);
        finish();***//remove this***
        return true;
```

if you tell the activity calling another activity to finish(),this basically means that activity called can neevr return to the previous activity, therefore this below is correct:
***//finish();has been removed***

```
 Intent d = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                PaymentActivity.class);
        startActivity(d);
        return true;
```

The next thing you need to do is make sure your manifest has parent activity added to the activities.

Eg:

```
<activity
        android:name=".PaymentActivity"
        android:label="@string/paymentlabel"
        android:parentActivityName=".PaymentActivity" />
```

And in your Payment Activity onCreate add,the following:

```
assert getSupportActionBar() != null;***> //this tells the application that ActionBar is not null and therefore dont call an java null exceptions and crash the activity
```

---

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```